# Problem with FindGeometricTransform and NMinimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization, bugs, geometry, geometric-transform

I'm interested in Centroidal Voronoi tessellation. Here are two examples of unit disk tessellations:

[image]

They are *the same* with respect to rotation.
Recently, I've found `FindGeometricTransform`. For a square it works well, but for disk I see a problem.
So here are data of mentioned tessellations (we need to find transformation only for seeds):

```
    seeds1 = {{0.775108, -0.241578}, {-0.792184, -0.056252}, {-0.101257, \
-0.787851}, {-0.182002, 0.791042}, {-0.150633, 
  0.393956}, {0.380565, -0.180766}, {0.713349, 
  0.293661}, {-0.340764, -0.0153295}, {0.208997, 
  0.192923}, {0.412246, -0.662962}, {-0.0408312, -0.337878}, \
{-0.63377, 0.455064}, {-0.556108, -0.526441}, {0.350942, 0.68688}}
    
    seeds2 = {{-0.802537, 0.109056}, {-0.227327, -0.761387}, {0.761821, 
  0.164738}, {-0.423125, -0.0215327}, {0.291033, 
  0.300411}, {0.705383, -0.364998}, {0.300652, -0.705072}, {0.488612, 
  0.648416}, {-0.0351534, 0.769755}, {-0.119228, 
  0.255533}, {0.306248, -0.150524}, {-0.0965345, -0.329819}, \
{-0.523693, 0.565791}, {-0.651289, -0.434905}}
```

Define distance between sets as:

```
arrDist[arr1_, arr2_] := Max[SquaredEuclideanDistance[
       First@Nearest[arr1, #], #] & /@ arr2];
```

and start to rotate one of set. We get such picture:

```
data = Table[arrDist[seeds1, RotationTransform[t][seeds2]], 
{t, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.01}]; ListPlot[data, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Obviously there are many local minima and one global. And if value of global minimum less than some tolerance (which is derived from region discretization properties), sets treated as the same.
But how to find it?!

`FindGeometricTransform` failed:

```
FindGeometricTransform[seeds1, seeds2]
```

[image]
`FindMinimum` failed 'cause we need global minimum:

```
goal[arr1_,arr2_,t_]:= arrDist[arr1, RotationTransform[t][arr2]] /; 
  MatrixQ[arr1, NumericQ] && MatrixQ[arr2, NumericQ] && 
   NumericQ[t];

FindMinimum[{goal[seeds1,seeds2,t], 0<=t<=2 \[Pi]},t]
{0.062312, {t -> 1.275423}}
```

`NMinimize` is better, but it's not global minimum:

```
NMinimize[{goal[seeds1, seeds2, t], 0 <= t <= 2 \[Pi]}, t,
 Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
{0.0207009, {t -> 0.027393}}
```

Manually (using above picture) we easily get

```
goal[seeds1, seeds2, 5.06]
0.000201137
```

What does all this mean and how do I end up comparing sets in terms of rotations?!

Answer (score 3):

I consider it to be a bug or at least inefficient algorithm.

When you provide permutation of `seeds2` that is consistent with order of `seeds1` then `FindGeometricTransform` is able to find the correct transformation.

I found the permutation of `seeds2` manually.

On the picture you can see in red points of `seeds1`, in green points of `seeds2` and in black points that are transformation of `seeds2`.

```
pseeds2 = seeds2[[{5, 7, 2, 9, 3, 8, 6, 1, 13, 10, 11, 12, 4}]];

FindGeometricTransform[seeds1, pseeds2, TransformationClass -> "Rigid"]

Graphics[{{PointSize[0.04], Red, Point[seeds1]}, {PointSize[0.04], 
   Green, Point[seeds2]}, {PointSize[0.02], Black, 
   GeometricTransformation[Point[seeds2], %[[2]]]}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used `DeleteDuplicates` on seeds in case there are duplicates, then sorted both seeds by angle (with error `0.1`) and by norm.

Then I found the minimum of total squared distance for all `14` rotations of `sseeds2` and `sseeds1` and choose the best one.

It is at rotation angle `fi->-1.22166` which is consistent with yours `t->5.06` because `-1.22166+2*π=5.06153`. Total squared distance is `0.000866629`.

```
seeds1=DeleteDuplicates@{{0.775108,-0.241578},{-0.792184,-0.056252},{-0.101257,-0.787851},{-0.182002,0.791042},{-0.150633,0.393956},{0.380565,-0.180766},{0.713349,0.293661},{-0.340764,-0.0153295},{0.208997,0.192923},{0.412246,-0.662962},{-0.0408312,-0.337878},{-0.63377,0.455064},{-0.556108,-0.526441},{0.350942,0.68688}};

seeds2=DeleteDuplicates@{{-0.802537,0.109056},{-0.227327,-0.761387},{0.761821,0.164738},{-0.423125,-0.0215327},{0.291033,0.300411},{0.705383,-0.364998},{0.300652,-0.705072},{0.488612,0.648416},{-0.0351534,0.769755},{-0.119228,0.255533},{0.306248,-0.150524},{-0.0965345,-0.329819},{-0.523693,0.565791},{-0.651289,-0.434905}};

sseeds1=SortBy[seeds1,{Round[Mod[ArcTan[#[[1]],#[[2]]],2 π],0.1]&,Norm[#]&}];
sseeds2=SortBy[seeds2,{Round[Mod[ArcTan[#[[1]],#[[2]]],2 π],0.1]&,Norm[#]&}];

len=Length[seeds1];

NMinimize[Total@(Flatten[(RotationTransform[fi][#])-sseeds1]^2),fi]&/@(RotateLeft[sseeds2,#]&/@Range[len]);

First@SortBy[%,First]

Clear[seeds1,seeds2,sseeds1,sseeds2,len]
```

---

```
{0.000866629,{fi->-1.22166}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for hours of exploration looks like next combination works.
Firstly, distance function should be cumulative, not maximise:

```
arrDist[arr1_, arr2_] := Total[SquaredEuclideanDistance[
       First@Nearest[arr1, #], #] & /@ arr2];
```

This makes goal function smoother:
[image]

Secondly, `Method` `"RandomSearch"` better for this task.
So `NMinimize` with such options find global minimum in all cases that I've explored and may be good alternative for `FindGeometricTransform` in case of continuous rotations.